# How to set enable=false to a item template inside a grid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I want to set `enable = false` according to the role

I have an `if` statement to check for the role

```
page load() {
    if(role == "something")
    {
        // I want to set imgbtn.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

How to do that.

```
<Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Controls" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtn_GroupEditClick" ToolTip="Edit Group" />
       <asp:ImageButton ID="img_Send" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Message.jpg" Enabled="True"
   runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("GroupName", "SendMessage.aspx?GroupName={0}") %>'
                                ToolTip="Create Message"></asp:ImageButton>


</ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupID" ItemStyle-Width="0%" HeaderText="GroupID" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="GroupName" />
     </columns>
```

I am doing databinding for the grid

Comment: ILO doing this the way you have, I've also used gator tags to tell javascript (or jquery) to fire... So instead of traversing a datagridview searching for types in the item template, it's just $('#imgbtn').attr('enabled','false');

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `RowDataBound` Grid's event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
       //Or you can use e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ur control id");
       foreach (object  c in e.Row.Cells[0].Controls)
       {
           ImageButton btn = c as ImageButton;
           if (c != null && role == "something")
           {
               //Do your logic here
           }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the RowDataBound event on the GridView like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = e.Row.FindControl("imgbtn") as Button;
    btn.Enabled = role == "something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one or more controls on the page you wish to enable or disable based on a role, you could create a public property in your page/control like so:

```
public bool BelongsToRoleA { get; set; }
```

Set its value based on the role

```
If(role==”something”)
{
    BelongsToRoleA = true;
}else
{
    BelongsToRoleA = false;
}
```

And then reference it in your markup like so:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" Enabled='<%# BelongsToRoleA %>' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a databinding expression and do it in the ASPX markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" Enabled='<%# role == "something" %>' ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:-

set on your .aspx.cs page

```
public string role { set; get; }
```

and in design part replace your code with this

```
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Controls" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <%if (role == "Something")
                  { %>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtn_GroupEditClick"
                        ToolTip="Edit Group" Enabled="false" />
                        <%}
                  else
                  { %>
                          <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtn_GroupEditClick"
                        ToolTip="Edit Group" Enabled="true" />
                        <%} %>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="img_Send" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Message.jpg" Enabled="True"
                        runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("GroupName", "SendMessage.aspx?GroupName={0}") %>'
                        ToolTip="Create Message"></asp:ImageButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupID" ItemStyle-Width="0%" HeaderText="GroupID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="GroupName" />
        </Columns>
```